# Setting text of textview in another class doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextview

Using a storyboard I've set up two different view controllers (A&B) where one of them (B) have a UITextView.

How can I access and change the text in the textview from View Controller A?

---

The code below doesn't give any errors but the text isn't set, even though the function is called correctly.

If I run `[self.desc setText:text];` inside viewDidLoad in ViewControllerB it works.

**ViewControllerA.h**

```
@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController
{
}

@end
```

**ViewControllerA.m**

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"
#import "ViewControllerB.h"
@interface ViewControllerA ()
@end

@implementation ViewControllerA
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        ViewControllerB *bInstance = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
        [bInstance setDescription:@"this is some new text";
    }
@end
```

**ViewControllerB.h**

```
@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController
{
    UITextView *desc;
}
- (void)setDescription:(NSString *) text;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *desc;
@end
```

**ViewControllerB.m**

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"

@interface ViewControllerB ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerB
@synthesize desc;

- (void)setDescription:(NSString *)text{
    NSLog(@"called!");
    [self.desc setText:text];
}

@end
```

Comment: Where do you launch ViewControllerB?

Comment: It's launched at the same time as ViewControllerA, ViewControllerB is inside a container in ViewControllerA

Comment: bInstance is another instance of the class not the same one?!

Comment: You must have a reference to the object you launched

Comment: I've setup all the views in storyboard, how can I reference that object?

Comment: add code you launch both classes and I will answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: I think that my comments answered your question. why you can't change text value. I added another answer. so feel free to accept one my solutions. :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not manipulate another view controller's views, ever. It is bad design in general, and often doesn't work at all (as you've discovered.)

Instead, set up a string property in your second view controller. Set that (in prepareForSegue, if you're using storyboards.)

Then, in your second view controller's viewWillAppear, put the string into the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController
{
    UITextView *desc;
@public
    ViewControllerB objB;
}
```

When you launch:

```
ObjectOfAToLaunch.objB = ObjectOfBToLaunch;
```

In view did load

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [Objb setDescription:@"this is some new text"];
}
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement prepareForSegue method in the controller that launch A and B.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        UIViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        if ([vc isKindOfClass:ViewControllerB])
        {
            ObjB = vc; // ObjB is a public member you must declare in interface
            if (ObjA!=nil)vc->ObjA = ObjB;
        }

        if ([vc isKindOfClass:ViewControllerA])
        {
            ObjA = vc; // ObjA is a public member you must declare in interface
            if (ObjB!=nil)vc->ObjA = ObjB;
        }
    }
}
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

bInstance is another instance of the class. not the same one.